# Angular - How to test setInteval with Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm working with an application with Angular 11.

I've a loginService that allows users to interact with their profiles.
In my application there's the jwt authentication and every 30 minutes the token is refreshed.

My LoginService looks like the following

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

    private intervalId: any;

    constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient,
                private readonly ngZone: NgZone) {
        this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {

            this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
                ngZone.run(() => {
                    this.renewJwtToken();
                });
            }, 1000 * 60 * 30);
        });
    }

    callLogin(loginRequest: LoginRequest): Observable<HttpResponse<LoginResponse>> {
        // call in order to login user
    }

    renewJwtToken() {
        // call in order to renew the token
    }
}
```

My problems are during the shallow tests (the ones in which we create the TestBed). I'm using jasmine 3.8 with karma 6.3.4

Every test returns with the following error

```
Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
            at <Jasmine>
```

If I comment the content of the LoginService constructor everything works fine.

How can I test my application without disabling the setInterval I have in the LoginService constructor?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

See if `fakeAsync` and `flush` will help you (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53864251/7365461). `fakeAsync` and `tick` will allow you to manually progress time, `tick` with no arguments will allow you to ensure all promises have completed (same as `flushMicroTasks()`) but timeout and interval are macrotasks and see if the `flush` command inside of a `fakeAsync` zone helps you.

I think since your `setInterval` is in the constructor, ensure your `service = TestBed.inject(LoginService);` is also in a `fakeAsync` zone.

Something like this:

```
import { fakeAsync, flush } from '@angular/core/testing';
....
beforeEach(fakeAsync(() => {
    service = TestBed.inject(LoginService);
    flush();
}));
```

The code running in `runOutsideAngular` might cause complications though so you can consider creating a re-usable service for `setInterval` and then just mocking this in your test. Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39448203/7365461).